# Django how to locate one specific row or container in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

For example, in one template, there are 10 rows of videos and I need to quickly go to the video number 7. How do I achieve that? I know in html, you can use anchor tag then href to the id tag. But how to switch it to django style?

Thanks

Comment: HTML is Django style.

Answer (score 0):

django can't access dom elements in templates. you are thinking with front-end logic. you can only pass the objects to template not handle them.

Comment: Got it! That is, I'll need to code all my way to that element, right?

Comment: Now i try to explain.

Answer (score 0):

first you must define url of view in urls.py:

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from search.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('index/', search),
]
```

then you need to define how objects sorted or listed and which template using during rendering in views:

views.py:

```
class HomeView(View):
      model = Listing
      template_name = 'index.html'
      def get(self, request, slug):
          list = self.model.objects.all()
          return render(request, self.template_name, locals())
```

and defines how displays at browser our objects in template:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- this is the tag that our objects will displayed within -->
<div id="some-id">
    <!-- just write this code for to pass objects to any tags -->
    {% for item in list %}
        <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
        <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```